# Laravel Form Questions

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

Two problems with using the Form class in laravel. Finding it hard to get used to the parameter passing with arrays I am using twitter bootstrap:

1. Adding a class to a select type does not work?
2. Using radio buttons to output properly

1

```
 {{ Form::select('title', array('Mr', 'Mrs', 'Ms', 'Miss', 'Master', 'Dr',   'Prof'), array('class' => 'input-small')) }}
```

2

```
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
  {{ Form::label('gender', 'Gender', array('class' => 'control-label')) }}
  <label class="radio">
  {{ Form::radio('gender', 'Male') }} Male
  </label>

  <label class="radio">
  {{ Form::radio('gender', 'Female') }} Female
  </label>
 <p class="help-block"> Please enter your gender</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You are passing the wrong values

```
public static function select($name, $options = array(), $selected = null, $attributes = array())
```

You must pass the selected value, session or `Input::old('name')`

```
{{ Form::select('title', array('Mr', 'Mrs', 'Ms', 'Miss', 'Master', 'Dr', 'Prof'), $selected = NULL,  array('class' => 'input-small')) }}
```

2) Looks fine on my templates, I have the same code. Can you post more info?

Comment: I'm a little confused on your comment that "You must pass the selected value, session or Input::old('name')" while your example is passing NULL to the function. Does NULL just mean to use whatever value it would have automatically calculated? My intuition says "yes", but I'm curious.

Comment: @MichaelCordingley If you review the function signature and source code it will probably answer your question a lot better than I ever could on here. The third parameter is the currently selected value, this can be from the session or the `Input::old('name')`. I can see my answer isn't clear, however the code snippet speaks clearer than my poor attempt at an explanation :)